# OpenGauss environment installation problem

Tags: python, environment, open-gauss

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/gsfile.py", line 31, in <module>
```

import psutil

```
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import _psutil_linux as cext
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/_psutil_linux.py", line 7, in <module>
__bootstrap__()
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/_psutil_linux.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
```

ImportError: `/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/_psutil_linux.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "gs_preinstall", line 32, in <module>
from gspylib.common.DbClusterInfo import dbClusterInfo, \
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/common/DbClusterInfo.py", line 36, in <module>
from gspylib.os.gsfile import g_file
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/gsfile.py", line 65, in <module>
```

import psutil

```
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from . import _pslinux as _psplatform
File "/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import _psutil_linux as cext
```

ImportError: `/opt/software/openGauss/script/gspylib/os/../../../lib/psutil/_psutil_linux.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the python dependency cannot be found. Look for the dependency package ‘psutil’